# How to merge data (CSV) files from multiple branches (Git and DVC)?

Tags: git, data-science, dvc

**Background**: In my projects I'm using GIT and [DVC](https://dvc.org/) to keep track of versions:

- GIT - only for source codes
- DVC - for dataset, model objects and outputs

I'm testing different approaches in separate branches, i.e:

- random_forest
- neural_network_1
- ...

Typically as an output I'm keeping predictions in csv file with standarised name (i.e.: pred_test.csv). As a consequence in different branches I've different pred_test.csv files. The structure of the file is very simple, it contains two columns:

- ID
- Prediction

**Question**: What is the best way to merge those prediction files into single big file?

I would like to obtain a file with structure:

- ID
- Prediction_random_forest
- Prediction_neural_network_1
- Prediction_...

My main issue is how to access files with predictions which are in different branches?

Comment: If you want to merge one CSV file's columns into another CSV file you should consider writing a script for that (be it bash, python, php or what-have-you). Git is not the right tool for that job.

Comment: I dont want to do that in GIT, I can do it in python or in whatever other language. The issue is how to access files that are in different branches.

Comment: Oh okay sure. Well there is no limit how often you can clone your Git repository. Just clone it into a different directory and checkout the other branch. The script can then loop over several directories with different branches checked out. I believe this is the easiest approach.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't thought about that approach, it should work.

Comment: maybe a better question title is "How to merge DVC outputs from multiple branches?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to use [`dvc get`](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/get) in this case:

```sh
dvc get -o random_forest_pred.csv --rev random_forest . pred_test.csv
```

It should bring the `pred_test.csv` from the `random_forest` branch.

> Mind the `.` before the `pred_test.csv` please, it's needed and it means that "use the current repo", since `dvc get` could also be used on other repos (e.g. GitHub URL)

Then I think you could use some CLI or write a script to join the files:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293775/merging-contents-of-multiple-csv-files-into-single-csv-file

Comment: Also they can specify another output name like `pred_test-2.csv` to use temporarily so both versions exist in the same workspace and can be merged with CSV processing tools.

Comment: Perfect! That was the solution that I was looking for!